# Is attending a priestly ordination, bishop's consecration, or religious profession an indulgenced act (pious work)?

Tags: catholicism, ordination, indulgence, religious-life

Is attending a priestly ordination, bishop's consecration, or religious profession an indulgenced act (pious work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my searching is correct, attending the ordination of a priest (or deacon), consecration of a bishop, or religious profession in itself is not an indulgences act; but the first Mass of a newly ordained priest is:

> INDULGENCES FOR ATTENDING THE FIRST MASS OF A NEWLY-ORDAINED PRIEST AND FOR KISSING HIS HANDS
>
> 1. To all the faithful who devoutly assist at the first Mass of any priest, a partial indulgence is granted; a plenary indulgence is granted if they are blood relatives of the priest to the third de- gree inclusive, and if they have obtained pardon for their sins, re- ceived Holy Communion and prayed for the intentions of the Pope.
> 2. To those who on the day of priestly ordination and on the day of the first Mass devoutly kiss the palms of the hands of the new priest, there is granted a partial indulgence.
>
> *Preces et Pia Opera*, 629. [as quoted in [*Ceremonies of Ordination to the Priesthood and Diaconate*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8471)]